# Laravel detach does not work - it just updates pivot columns to null instead of detaching whole model

Tags: laravel

I want to detach Skill model from User model, but instead of detaching, `detach($skillId)` method is just updating pivot columns to null.

I made route DELETE /skills/{skillId} and in Controller I returned detach metod on skills relationship.

Relation:

```
public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'user_skill', 'user_id', 'skill_id')
            ->withPivot(['scale', 'started_at'])
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Delete:

```
return auth()->user()->skills()->detach($skillId);
```

Pivot columns were updated to null, but the attached model still remains.

Comment: Did you use softDeletes on the pivot model?

Comment: No, but I checked that also to make sure I didn't use

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly. The problem is that detached skills are not deleted from the database? `detach` and `attach` only modify the pivot table.

Comment: If I'm detaching Skill model from User model, that means detach method will remove whole row with user_id, skill_id and other pivot columns as well? For me, only pivot columns are null after detaching, but user_id and skill_id remain the same - it's like attached but without pivot columns

See image:
http://i.imgur.com/muAk4dS.png

Comment: Can you see what the query log is showing? `DB::enableQueryLog(); auth()->user()->skills()->detach($skillId); dd(DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me to use query log totally forgot about it. With that, I figured out I forgot to clear route:cache. So, when I called DELETE for some reason Laravel remembered PUT.

Comment: There you go. Sometimes it's the simplest things.